# THE AUTHENTIC TOR?

Tags: security

Could  there  be  such  a  thing  as  an  "imposter"  Tor?

Could  anyone  mistakenly  download  an  "imposter"  version  of  Tor?

Thank you,

Tomadeus

Answer (score 0):

It does exists. When I helped people I saw some examples of fake Tor and Tor Browser Bundle distributions. One of them was so good-tinkered that even mimiced tor's standart output and error messages, *and even tried to work*!

Comment: Thank  you Alexey.  How  does  one  verify a "signature?"

Comment: like [this](https://www.torproject.org/docs/verifying-signatures.html.en) via GnuPG